# extract info from json - beginner

Tags: php, json

Hi I am having trouble extracting all the variable from this json. can anyone help?

```
{"name@email.com":[{"action":"open","timestamp":"2015-03-24 17:31:02","url":null,"ip":"212.126.37.01"},{"action":"open","timestamp":"2015-03-24 17:31:03","url":null,"ip":"212.126.37.01"}]}
```

I used json_decode and got this:

```
Array ( [name@email.com] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [action] => open [timestamp] => 2015-03-24 17:31:02 [url] => [ip] => 212.126.37.01 ) [1] => Array ( [action] => open [timestamp] => 2015-03-24 17:31:03 [url] => [ip] => 212.126.37.01 ) ) )
```

I tried:

```
$newarray = json_decode($array, true);
echo $newarray[0]['action'];
```

but no luck

I want extract the email too as there are a lot of other json data with different emails. To give some insight this is a feed from the Mailchimp export api.
any pointers or links would be great thanks
Dave

Comment: That's not json. That's an ordinary array.

Comment: yes thanks. It was but I used json_decode , I'll update the question

Comment: `$newarray['name@email.com'][0]['action'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple loop to access data in example json is:

```
foreach( json_decode( $array ) as $key => $value ) {
    print_r( $key );    // name@email.com

    foreach( $value as $info ) {
        print_r( $info->action );
        print_r( $info->timestamp );
        print_r( $info->url );
        print_r( $info->ip );
    }
}
```